# Make the inside of a complex object "thicker"?

Tags: objects, solidify-modifier

Note: Mostly a blender beginner.

I printed out a scale 3D object at a 1:150 scale, and the walls of the object became so thin they were brittle.  Most of the object was OK, just the "bucket" part of it was effected.

Original Model link: https://www.printables.com/model/181911-nederlandse-spoorwegen-railpro-fccpps-ballastwagen/
[image: blender screenshot]

So I tried to make the walls thicker in just this part by selecting the faces and adding a "solidify" modifier to them.  However this made them thicker in weird ways, with polygonal objects jutting out both the inside and outside of the object.

Is there a better way to do this?  The only other thing I can think of is to select every face manually and extrude it.  But the triangular tessellation of the round corners would make this a very laborious task.

[image]

Comment: You can add the blend file by going to https://blend-exchange.com/ and following the instructions there.

Answer (score 2):

Save the faces you want to thicken as a vertex group and then use that vertex group in a displace modifier. This will allow you to control the offset of those faces along the normal of those faces. You also get fine control to tweak how much thicker you want those faces. Using Alt-B you can draw a rectangle that will allow you to clip away geometry. This will allow you to view something similar to a "cross section" of the region you chose to clip. You can create different vertex groups for different groups of faces and use those different vertex groups with different displace modifiers and have different amounts of offsets for different parts of the complex object.